# Comparing two anagrams in C

Tags: c, strings

This is a simple attempt by me to test whether two words are anagrams or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define CH_LEN 15
#define N 26

int main(void) {
    char track_letters[N] = {0};
    char first_word[CH_LEN];
    char sec_word[CH_LEN];
    printf("Enter first word: ");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < CH_LEN; i++) {
        first_word[i] = getchar();
        if(first_word[i] == '\n')
            break;
        if(!isalpha(first_word[i]))
            --i;

        track_letters[(tolower(first_word[i]) - 'a')]++;


    }
    printf("Enter second word: ");
    for(i = 0; i < CH_LEN; i++) {
        sec_word[i] = getchar();
        if(sec_word[i] == '\n')
            break;
        if(!isalpha(sec_word[i]))
            --i;
        track_letters[(tolower(sec_word[i]) - 'a')]--;

    }
    for(i = 0; i < CH_LEN; i++) {
        if(track_letters[i] != 0) {
            printf("The words are not anagrams");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("The words are anagrams");

    return 0;
}
```

You can use any method of C (structure, pointers, functions etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You limit yourself to anagrams of 15 letters.

```
#define CH_LEN 15
char first_word[CH_LEN];
char sec_word[CH_LEN];
```

But you don't actually use words after they are input.
You can fix the limitation (and a potentially serious bug) by not using the concept of a line. Just read characters.

In the code just read characters:

```
char nextInput = getchar();
```

No all alphabets are 26 letters.

```
#define N 26
```

I would have done this for clarity to show that you are looking at a-z:

```
#define N  ('z' - 'a' + 1)
```

Also N is not that descriptive. Personally I would have preferred a global static variable.

```
static const AlphabetSize = ('z' - 'a' + 1);
```

You basically repeat the same piece of code twice. This violates the DRY principle. Remove this code into a function and call the function passing parameters for the differences.

```
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < CH_LEN; i++) {
        first_word[i] = getchar();
        if(first_word[i] == '\n')
            break;
        if(!isalpha(first_word[i]))
            --i;

        track_letters[(tolower(first_word[i]) - 'a')]++;


    }
    printf("Enter second word: ");
    for(i = 0; i < CH_LEN; i++) {
        sec_word[i] = getchar();
        if(sec_word[i] == '\n')
            break;
        if(!isalpha(sec_word[i]))
            --i;
        track_letters[(tolower(sec_word[i]) - 'a')]--;

    }
```

I would write like this:

```
    ProcessesAnagram(track_letters, +1);  // Reads first Line
    ProcessesAnagram(track_letters, -1);  // Reads second line
```

Since we are not longer bound by a word size. I would change the loop to check for the end of line (or end of input)).

```
 void ProcessesAnagram(int* track_letters, int increment)
 {
    int nextLetter = getchar();
    for(;nextLetter != EOF && nextLetter != '\n'; nextLetter = getchar())
    {
        if(!isalpha(nextLetter)
        {    continue;           // If not a letter just start the next iteration
        }

        // Note: increment is +1 first anagram
        //       increment is -1 second anagram (so they will cancel out)
        track_letters[(tolower(nextLetter) - 'a')] += increment;    
    }
 }
```

There is a bug here

You are using the wrong size: `CH_LEN` is the size of the words. But the track_letters array has a size of `N`.

```
    for(i = 0; i < CH_LEN; i++) {
        if(track_letters[i] != 0) {
            printf("The words are not anagrams");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In a non-26-char alphabet, the extra chars are not going to be between 'a' and 'z', are they? Also, the `continue` is not really necessary; just reverse the condition.

Comment: @WilliamMorris: Both good points. But I don't mind the continue. In my opinion (and this is totally depended on context and how your team feels so can be very variable) I think the error test and continue helps show state that are not being considered thus makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Loki said, I would have taken the two words from the command line and I would split the checking code into a separate function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int track_letters[N] = {0};
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s word1 word2\n", argv[0]);
    } else {
        processes_anagram(track_letters, argv[1], 1);
        processes_anagram(track_letters, argv[2], -1);
        check_letters(track_letters);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also add a \n onto the printf strings